# Spring environment variable values computing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Can I somehow use environment variable to set a properties value, but using computing, something like this:

```
test2: ${TEST+1:2} 
test: ${TEST:1}
```

As you can see the default values are `1` and `2` and I want the same if it's being set from environment variable. I want to do this in my `application.properties/application.yml` file, not in code.

Comment: Do you want to use this 'logic' in your application.properties/application.yml file?

Comment: @MevlütÖzdemir, yes

Comment: In `test2: ${TEST+1:2} ` if value of `TEST` env var is 5, you want `test2` property value to be 6 i.e. 5 + 1?

Comment: @Smile, yes, but automatically, without touching it in the code

Answer (score 0):

There's System.getEnv from the Java Standart Library to get Env Variables.

Comment: I want to do it properties file, updated the question

Comment: This might be what you‘re looking for: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html